# JavaScript AJAX PHP issue

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Ok. I need help with this. For some reason the onreadystatechange is fired multiple times. I really need to get this figured out tonight. It's the last task I have left and I don't know what to do or what's causing it. Please help.

I'm using AJAX (ndhr) to send over JSON 'Y-m-d h:i:s' to PHP to use the strtotime() function to return 'm-d-Y' back through AJAX. The JSON and PHP work great, but when the onreadystatechange is fired it does it multiple times. Almost like the readyState == 4 more times than it does.

```
var divs_d = ["d_2009", "d_2010", "d_2011"];

function ajax_get_json(cdiv,ocdv,ed){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("GET", "/json/sample.json", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
    hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            cdiv.innerHTML = "";
            var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            var cad = data.comm_archive;
            var rndate;
            var nda = new Array();
            var ndac = 0;
            var ec = 0;

            for (ni = 0; ni < cad.length; ni++) {
                if (cad[ni].year == ocdv) {
                    ec = ec + 1;
                    ed.innerHTML = '<h4>' + ocdv + ' (' + ec + ' entries)</h4>';

                    var ndhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    var url = "/inc/strtotime.php";
                    var vars = "ndate=" + cad[ni].publish_date;
                    ndhr.open("POST", url, true);
                    ndhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    ndhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (ndhr.readyState == 4 && ndhr.status == 200) {
                            nda[ndac] = ndhr.responseText;
                            ndac = ndac + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    ndhr.send(vars);
                }
            }

            nda.sort(function (a, b) { return b - a });
            for (ndai = 0; ndai < ndac; ndai++) {
                cdiv.innerHTML += '<h4><a href="/this_is_a_Test/archive.php?cdate=' + nda[ndai] + '">' + nda[ndai] + '</a></h4>';
            }
        }
    }
    hr.send(null);
}

function optionCchange() {
    var ocdv = document.getElementById("optionCdate").value;
    var ed = document.getElementById("ediv");

    for (i = 0; i < divs_d.length; i++) {
        var cdiv = document.getElementById(divs_d[i]);

        if (divs_d[i] == "d_" + ocdv) {
            cdiv.className = "bddiv show";
            ajax_get_json(cdiv,ocdv,ed);
        } else {
            cdiv.className = "bddiv hide";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How, exactly?  You haven't given us any of the needed information.  What problem are you experiencing?  What error is it throwing, what is your php outputting.. these are all things we need to know that you haven't provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ndhr.onreadystatechange` function `ndhr` represents the last `ndhr` created in the loop not the calling one, to reference the calling object use `this`.

```
 ndhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         nda[ndac] = this.responseText;
         ndac = ndac + 1;
     }
 }
```

The `the last for(ndai = 0; ndai < ndac; ndai++)` is behaving as you expect because of the asynchronous  nature of ajax, by the time that code is executed the ajax requests have not finished yet. You'll have to execute this code in the on ready change state callback. Just use a counter to check if all the ajax requests have finished then execute the code.

Comment: Yea. I just noticed that when I put alert(nda[0]); before the for loop, it shows undefined and then when I close the alert the results show. When I remove the alert from the code, no results show.

Comment: How do you use a counter to check if the code is complete? I'm using settimeout right now as a work around waiting seconds for the code to finish. the last for loop only needs to be called once. I'm using ndhr AJAX to create an array of the final dates I need to create the divs with the last for loop.

Comment: @yanike Well you already have a counter there `ndac`, just check when it is equal to `cad.length` the run the code.

Comment: Nice. I'm going to use the "ni". Thanks Musa!

Answer (score 0):

If you need run the code **once**, you don't have to be anxious about how many times `readystate 4` was fired. Simply use a boolean variable to check if the block of code has been executed.

Here's a pseudocode example of my idea.

```
executed = false;
if (readystate && (executed == false))
    {
      blablabla;
      executed = true;
    }
else
    {
      sry your code has been executed;
    }
```